# Maximal Subset of Linearly Independent Elements

Tags: linear-algebra

*Theorem.* Let {$v_{1},...,v_{n}$} be a set of generators of a vector space V. Let {$v_{1},...,v_{r}$} (for $r \leq n$) be a maximal subset of linearly independent elements. Than {$v_{1},...,v_{r}$} is a basis of $V$.

Proof. We must prove that $v_{1},...,v_{r}$ generate V.

My question is that is proof obivous? Since we already have {$v_{1},...,v_{n}$} is a set of generators of a vector space V, $v_{1},...,v_{r}$ generate V (because we already have {$v_{1},..,v_{r},..., v_{n}$} is set of generators of V. You can correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is true that $\{\nu_1,\dots,\nu_n\}$ generate $V$, but why does it follow that any subset does as well? For example, how would you prove that $\ni_n$ is contained in the span of $\{\nu_1,\dots,\nu_r\}$?

Comment: @nelv So, propbaly, I don't understand what ''{$v_{1},...,v_{n}$} generate (span) $V$'' is mean. Can you explain detailed of span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty simple proof, but it does not follow simply from the fact that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r\}$ is a subset of $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n\}$. You have to use the fact that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r\}$ is a **maximal** subset of $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n\}$ of linearly independent elements. There are two steps:

1. $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r\}$ generates $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n\}$.

Let $i$ be such that $i < r \leq n$. The former is a maximal subset of the latter of linearly independent elements. This means that if $v_i$ is added to the former, the set will no longer be linearly independent because any superset of the maximal subset can not be linearly independent by the definition of maximal subset. Therefore, $v_i$ must be a linear combination of the elements in $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r\}$ because adding it to the set makes the set no longer linearly independent. Thus, $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r\}$ generates all $v_i$ for $i < r \leq n$, so it generates the whole set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_n\}$.

2. Since $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r\}$ generates a set that generates the vector space V and it is a set of linearly independent vectors, $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, ..., v_r\}$ is  a basis for V.

Comment: So, propbaly, I don't understand what ''{$v_{1},...,v_{n}$} generate (span) $V$'' is mean. Can you explain detailed of span?

Comment: If $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$ generates $V$, then that means any element $\alpha \in V$ can be found with a linear combination of $\{v_1, ..., v_n\}$. However, if you take a subset $\{v_1, ..., v_r\}$, then there might be some elements that need $v_{r+1}$ in order to be created, so $\{v_1, ..., v_r\}$ does not necessarily generate $V$. However, the above proof shows that if the subset is a maximal subset of linearly independent elements, then it does generate $V$.

Comment: Here's an example: Let's say $\Bbb{R}$ are scalars and $\Bbb{C}$ are vectors. Clearly, $\{1, i\}$ spans $\Bbb{C}$ because all complex numbers can be written in the form $a+bi$ for $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$. However, if we just take the subset $\{i\}$, then we no longer span $\Bbb{C}$ because a linear combination of $\{i\}$ would just be $ai$ for $a \in \Bbb{R}$ and complex numbers like $1+i$ can not be expressed like that.

Comment: I understood. Thanks for your answer.